# Does a non terminal token need an explicit definition?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, bison, yacc

I am writing code in bison that parses various assembly instruction. Here is a tidbit:

```
text
    : text NEWLINE Instruction
    | Instruction
    ;

Instruction
    : r-type
    {
        instruction.format = IF_R;
        instruction.opcode = 0b0110011;
    }
    ;

r-type
    : add
    {
        instruction.funct3 = 0x0;
        instruction.funct7 = 0x00;
    }
    ;

add
    : ADD REGISTER COMMA REGISTER COMMA REGISTER
    {
        instruction.rd = $2;
        instruction.rs1 = $4;
        instruction.rs2 = $6;
    }
    ;
```

Assume that `instruction` (lowercase) is a struct, and the (ALL CAPS) tokens are received from a lexer.

Does the 'add' non-terminal need to have a grammar rule that says `$$ = *something*;` or is this set up fine. Also is it fine to have multiple semantic rules along the token chain?

I have tried getting help from AI. It says that the non-terminal nodes are not defined. and the way that I write my semantic tokens is not standard. the rest of it is nonsense jargon.

Comment: Please [edit] and format code as code (indent each code line 4 spaces).

Comment: There is a default *action* in grammar rules of { `$$ = $1; }`, but yes you do have to have a rule for a non-terminal. Otherwise it's undefined. `add` is not a token but a non-terminal, These are mutually exclusive terms: don't confuse them. And yes you can have 'multiple actions along the token chain', but they may add s/r conflicts. I edited your post to show how to format .y files for readability. There are no doubt other ways, but this one has worked for me for 36 years.